# SimpleTest - Web Browser - Transfer Authentication to Client

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, simpletest

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I figured this was a great place to ask the question.

I'm using http://simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html PHP WebBrowser to test a wordpress site. What I'm doing is setting the login credentials to access the wordpress backend. I run a couple of test, but my question is in certain situations I want to transfer the session that the "SimpleTest PHP Web Browser" has running to client's browser. Aka... my browser.

So in a since I"m transferring the session from the server side test browser to a normal client browser. This "client browser" is the same browser that is literally running the SimpleTest script to begin with.

I'm wondering if I can transfer the header & cookies associated with the "SimpleTest PHP Web Browser" to my browser. What I'm thinking is to pull the data out using the SimpleTest PHP Library and then set that information to the client browser using Javascript.

Is this even possible? I feel like I'm missing some basic understanding of server side session authentication which would make this impossible.

Any ideas? I'm really curious!

Comment: I don't know the simpletest browser but, if you can get the cookies, you could pass them on to the "real" browser like you outline it in your question.

Comment: Thanks Hakre, I'm trying to do that now. However some of the cookies have dynamic names. like... "wordpress_17f7f14ddd4819eaaf17884d4965803d" and I'm not seeing a way to pull those names out from a list function using that SimpleTest PHP Library. I'll keep working on it and update as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [Authentication documentation](http://www.simpletest.org/en/authentication_documentation.html) for SimpleTest?